# Update data list in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, fancybox, jstl

I want to insert data from AJAX (XmlHttp), and, after inserting, I need to get all data retrieve back to be displayed in a fancybox popup. I have the below code, in a jsp page, and use it to create a jstl variable.

```
`<c:set var="List_of_OrderSet" value="${orderSetList}" scope="session" ></c:set>`
```

`scope="session"` 
Does this mean that I can get this list in any page?

```
   <table style="width: 1400px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="orderSet">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Sr</th>
                            <th>Order Date</th>
                            <th>Service Name</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>IsExternal</th>
                            <th>Care Professional</th>
                            <th>Remarks</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody >
                        <c:if test="${! empty List_of_OrderSet}">
                            <c:forEach var="complaint" items="${List_of_OrderSet}">

                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${complaint.orderStatus ne 'true' }">
                                        <tr class="gradeX" style="color: red;" >
                                            <td width="10px;"><input type="radio" name="btnRadio" id="btnRadio"  value="${complaint.patientOrderSetIDP},${complaint.createdByIDF},${complaint.lastModifiedByIDF},${complaint.orderStatus}" onclick="editOrderSet('OrderSetEdit',this.value)" /></td>
                                            <td width="20px;"><%=count++ %> </td>
                                            <td width="80px;" ><c:out value="${complaint.orderDate}"></c:out></td>
                                            <td ><c:out value="${complaint.serviceName}"></c:out></td>
                                            <td ><c:out value="${complaint.quantity}"></c:out></td>
                                            <td >
                                                <c:choose> 
                                                    <c:when test="${complaint.isExternal eq true}">
                                                        <c:out value="Yes"></c:out>
                                                    </c:when>
                                                    <c:otherwise>
                                                        <c:out value="No"></c:out>
                                                    </c:otherwise> 
                                                </c:choose> </td>
                                            <!-- 
                                            <td ><c:set var="IsExternal" value="${complaint.isExternal}"></c:set>
                                                <% if(pageContext.getAttribute("IsExternal").equals(true)) { %>Yes<% }
                                                else { %>No<% } %>
                                            </td>
                                            -->
                                            <td ><c:out value="${complaint.careProfessionalName}"></c:out></td>
                                            <td width="280px;" ><c:out value="${complaint.remarks}"></c:out></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </c:when>
                                    <c:otherwise>
                                        <tr class="gradeX">
                                        <td width="10px;"><input type="radio" name="btnRadio" id="btnRadio"  value="${complaint.patientOrderSetIDP},${complaint.createdByIDF},${complaint.lastModifiedByIDF},${complaint.orderStatus}" onclick="editOrderSet('OrderSetEdit',this.value)" /></td>
                                        <td width="20px;"><%=count++ %> </td>
                                        <td width="80px;" ><c:out value="${complaint.orderDate}"></c:out></td>
                                        <td ><c:out value="${complaint.serviceName}"></c:out></td>
                                        <td ><c:out value="${complaint.quantity}"></c:out></td>
                                        <td >
                                            <c:choose> 
                                                <c:when test="${complaint.isExternal eq true}">
                                                    <c:out value="Yes"></c:out>
                                                </c:when>
                                                <c:otherwise>
                                                    <c:out value="No"></c:out>
                                                </c:otherwise> 
                                            </c:choose> </td>
                                        <!-- 
                                        <td ><c:set var="IsExternal" value="${complaint.isExternal}"></c:set>
                                            <% if(pageContext.getAttribute("IsExternal").equals(true)) { %>Yes<% }
                                            else { %>No<% } %>
                                        </td>
                                        -->
                                        <td ><c:out value="${complaint.careProfessionalName}"></c:out></td>
                                        <td width="280px;" ><c:out value="${complaint.remarks}"></c:out></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </c:otherwise>
                                </c:choose>

                            </c:forEach>
                        </c:if>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

The list is displayed properly, but it is not updated after insert. Do I have to make and refresh the `<div>`? Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

try out this javascript function..

```
$('#divID').load('your.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: But Loading new jsp file cause a problem in fancybox closing .